# Why is this Python test failing?

Tags: python, django

Why is this Python test failing? I am using Django1.6 py33.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Summator:
    def summ(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from userprofile.models import Summator

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3

    def test_summator(self):
        f = Summator()
        assert f.summ(self.a, self.b) != self.a + self.b
```

python manage.py test

as a result I get the following output in the console

[image]

Comment: You probably meant == instead of != in your assert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you assert that `a+b` is not equal to `a+b`? Do this:

```
assert f.summ(self.a, self.b) == self.a + self.b
```

Comment: or use `self.assertEqual()`..